# usage of return

Tags: vb.net, return

I've seen a code where return is used like below

```
If myFunction() Then Return

Private Function myFunction() As Boolean
   Try //something
      return true
   Catch
      return false
   End Try
End Function
```

I didn't quite get the logic with the "If myFunction() Then return"
Any explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: please use the standard way of IF STATEMENT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Return` means to exit the function which returns no value. It's equivalent of `Exit Sub` in VB6 (if you are familiar with the language).

For example, if I have the following code:

```
Sub Foo()
    If True Then Return
    MessageBox.Show("Hello World");
End Sub
```

The message box will never show because `Return` exits the function.

For your case, let's replace `If True Then Return` with `If myFunction() Then Return`:

```
Sub Foo()
    If myFunction() Then Return
    MessageBox.Show("Hello World");
End Sub

Function myFunction As Boolean
    Try 'something
        Return True
    Catch
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

If myFunction returns true, then the message box will not show. If myFunction fails, then the message box will show.

Answer (score 2):

The If statement works the following way

```
If 'condition' Then 'do something'
```

'condition' can either be true or false. If it is true, 'do something' will be executed.
myFunction() returns such a true/false value (called Boolean), you can thus write it in the spot of the 'condition'.

Answer (score 1):

If myFunction returns true, then it will return. If myFunction returns false, then it will continue.

I assume in your example that the If statement is out of context (and is actually part of some other Function or subroutine).